# Predicate that parses a CSV list and matches partial values in Linq

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-entities

I am using the code snippet below to parse a list of zip codes from a form and then building a predicate to return records from the Entity that match any zip codes in the parsed list.

```
List<string> zips = ParseCSV("90210,56387,20015");
predicate = predicate.And(n => zips.Contains(n.ZIP));
```

Now a new requirement has come up that says that the comma delimited list might contain partial zip codes and that these should be returned too.  I would normally do this with a Contains.  `n.ZIP.Contains("902")`

But if the list of zips now becomes as below:

```
List<string> zips = ParseCSV("902,56387,215"); 
predicate = predicate.And(n => zips.Contains(n.ZIP));
```

I am not sure how to go about this when I am already doing a contains on the zips.  Any suggestions?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will check if there is any partial zip code, which is contained in ZIP:

```
predicate = predicate.And(n => zips.Any(z => n.ZIP.Contains(z)));
```